# NVIDIA RTX GPU via BOOTCAMP or AMD GPU via macOS Metal rendering

Tags: graphics-cards, windows, rendering, macos, macbook

Should I use a NVIDIA RTX 3060 Ti for Blender Cycles X via BOOTCAMP, or

AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT via Metal macOS Rendering (when it is officially released)

Computer specs: Intel Core i5-8210Y 8GB LPDDR3 RAM 2133 MHz

PS if you need any other info feel free to let me know and I will add it

Thanks

Comment: I think the 3060ti is better if you can get it for the same price as the rx 5600xt

Comment: if you get NVidia it won't be properly supported on macOS… though neither is the 5600 XT. The lowest spec XT supported is the 5700. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208544 for details of Apple eGPU support. Another thing to bear in mind is that with a low-end Mac like the Air, it could be quite easy to load it up with a hugely powerful GPU that the CPU just cannot keep up with.

Comment: I told you that the NVIDIA card would be under bootcamp

Comment: Just pointing out you'd only be able to use it at all in Windows, not the Mac. Anyway, I still think you're trying to put a Ferrari engine in a Lada. You'll be fine until the first corner ;))